# WLAN-Card for Lenovo Z50-70 laptop

Tags: laptop, wifi, wlan

A few weeks ago I bought a Lenovo [Z50-70](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-z-series-laptops/lenovo-z50-70) laptop (with i7-4510U). I'm very happy with this notebook. It is super fast and has a great graphics card (for how I use it). But there is only a slow 11b/g/n WiFi card, so no 5GHz band.

I found [this specification](http://psref.lenovo.com/PSREFUploadFile%5CSys/PDF/Lenovo%20Laptops/Lenovo%20Z50/Lenovo_Z50-70_spec.pdf) for the WiFi card:

> One of the following, configurable by model:
>
> • 11 b/g/n, 1x1, Wi-Fi + BT4.0 combo adapter, M.2 Card
> • 11 ac,1x1, Wi-Fi + BT4.0 combo adapter, M.2 Card
> • Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160, 1x1, Wi-Fi + BT4.0 combo adapter, M.2 Card

Amazon [sells an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IOS19E6) card.

How do I know if this card fits? Will it be compatible with the antenna of the notebook ?

Could you tell my how to look this up, or if this card will work ? Maybe you have a hint for some other WiFi cards ?

Comment: I donno about regular lenovos but Thinkpads have a whitelist of cards and they must have specific firmware for it. You can work around that tho.

Comment: You should try calling Lenovo support. They should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop's [hardware manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g_z_50_series_hmm.pdf) and [user guide](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g40_g50_z40_z50_ug_english.pdf) show no expansion slot for a [PC Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Card) WiFi Adapter.

Therefore, replacing the factory-installed internal Mini-PCIe card with a Mini-PCIe card with is 2.4 / 5 GHz capable is a reasonable choice. You may also consider adding an external WiFi device, such as a USB-attached WiFi 5GHz adapter if you are reticent to open the laptop, but, truly, it's easy to do.

I've replaced many of that model with no problem. It will fit and the antenna connections are the same as the previous card. Pages 39-40 of your [hardware manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g_z_50_series_hmm.pdf) provide specific illustrated instructions.